# Ошибка при сохранении данных из формы

Tags: php, wordpress

Пытаюсь сохранить данные из формы `contact form 7`, но при сохранении изображения выдаёт ошибку `Specified file failed upload test`.

```
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_custom_save_form_fields");
function wpcf7_custom_save_form_fields($cf7) {
    // get the contact form object
    $wpcf = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();

    $errors = [];
    $name = isset($_POST['your-name'])? sanitize_text_field($_POST['your-name']) : '';
    $email = isset($_POST['your-email'])? sanitize_text_field($_POST['your-email']) : '';
    $textarea = isset($_POST['your-message'])? sanitize_textarea_field($_POST['your-message']) : '';
    $fields = array( // подготовим массив с полями поста, ключ это название поля, значение - его значение
        'post_title'   => $name, // заголовок поста
        'post_content' => $textarea, // контент,
        'post_type' => 'thegem_testimonial', // контент,
        'post_status' => 'pending'
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($fields); // добавляем пост в базу и получаем его id
    if(!empty($email)){
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'email', $email);
    }

    $file = (!empty($_FILES) && isset( $_FILES['your-photo'] )) ? $_FILES['your-photo'] : null;
    if (!empty($file)) { // если основное фото было загружено
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

        $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'your-photo', $post_id );
        if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
            echo "Ошибка загрузки медиафайла.";
        } else {
            update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attachment_id); // привязываем миниатюру к посту
        }
    }

    return $wpcf;
}
```

из-за чего это может быть?
т.е. ошибка происходит после этой строки: `$attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'your-photo', $post_id );`

Comment: есть ли варианты, как это решить?

Comment: может кому пригодится https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804191/how-to-keep-uploaded-file-or-attachment-on-server-directory-contact-form-7